# OpenGL: How to check if the user GFX card can render with my shader?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, fallback

I need to make a fallback if the user doesnt support the shader i have made to render some things faster.

So, how exactly do i check these things? I know some of the shader functions are not supported by some GLSL versions, but, where is the complete list of these functions vs versions they need?

But the problem is, i dont know what exactly i need to know in order to know who can render that shader. Is it only about checking which function is supported by which GLSL version? or is there something more to know? I want to be **100%** sure when to switch to fallback render and when to use GLSL render.

I know how to retrieve the GLSL and OpenGL version strings.

Comment: There is no 100%, just think of screwed driver OpenGL implmentations...

Comment: @drahnr, how do they do it to be 99% sure? list all possible gfx cards/driver versions for all possibilities ? :|

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If [`glLinkProgram`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glLinkProgram.xml) sets the GL error state then the shader(s) are not compatible with the card.

Comment: Be advised though that on some ATI cards LinkProgram returns an error stating "Shader linked successfully" :P

Comment: @kornel, i was afraid this would happen... so, how does the big boys do it? do they just list all possible gfx cards configs for each of the shaders ? :|

Comment: @Kornel: That's the link ***log***, not the error.  Check the error with `glError` (call beforehand to clear the error, then after to check for new errors).

Comment: how exactly i use this glerror() ? i cant google it, cant find manual page

Comment: @Rookie: Sorry, misspelled it, should be [`glGetError`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/glGetError/)

Comment: oh, so i should check: `if(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR)` to see if the shader will work correctly on the user GPU?

Comment: @Rookie: Essentially.  `while (glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR); glLinkProgram(...); if (glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR) /* all is ok */;`

Comment: why the while loop? doesnt it work fine if i call it only once before glLinkProgram() ? and if you really need the while loop there, dont you need a while loop AFTER the glLinkProgram() too then?

Comment: @Rookie: OpenGL maintains a list of errors.  When the list is empty, `glGetError` returns `GL_NO_ERROR`.  Otherwise `glGetError` removes the first error and returns it.  `if (glGetError == GL_NO_ERROR)` after calling `glLinkProgram` already tells you the list is empty, there's no need to call it again.

Answer (score 1):

After calling `glLinkProgram`, it is advised to check the *link status*, by using :

```
glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linkStatus);
```

This will give you a boolean value indicating if the program linked fine. You also have a `GL_COMPILE_STATUS` available.

Most of the time, this will indicate if the program fails to compile or link on your platform.

Be advised, though, that a program may link fine but not be suitable to run on your hardware, in this case the GL rendering will fallback on *software rendering*, and be slow slow slow.

In this case, if you're lucky, you'll get a message in this link log, but this message is platform dependent.